# get_context_data in mixin not being called

Tags: django

I'm new to Django. I want to use a mixin to return some data to multiple class based views. It seems the `get_context_data` I defined in mixin is not called in the view class.

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super(MyMixin, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        from django.utils import timezone
        data['object'].now = timezone.now()
        return data

class PageDetail(DetailView, MyMixin):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'page-detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super(PageDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return data
```

Comment: You should define your `MyMixin` before the `DetailView`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define the base classes in the *wrong* order:

```
class PageDetail(DetailView, MyMixin):
    # ...
```

means that the [*method resolution order (MRO)*](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) is defined as:

```
>>> PageDetail.__mro__
(<class 'PageDetail'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.detail.DetailView'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.detail.BaseDetailView'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.View'>,
 <class 'MyMixin'>,
 <class 'object'>)
```

So that means that if we follow the `super(PageDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)`, this will *never* reach `MyMixin`, since the `ContextMixin` defines this as:

> ```
> class ContextMixin:
>
>     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
>         if 'view' not in kwargs:
>             kwargs['view'] = self
>         if self.extra_context is not None:
>             kwargs.update(self.extra_context)
>         return kwargs
> ```

and thus does *not* call any `super()` method.

You should define your `PageDetail` as:

```
class PageDetail(MyMixin, DetailView):
    # ...
```

So now the MRO is defined as:

```
>>> PageDetail.__mro__
(<class 'PageDetail'>,
 <class 'MyMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.detail.DetailView'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.detail.BaseDetailView'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.View'>,
 <class 'object'>)
```

and thus the `super(PageDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)` will call the `get_context_data` of the `MyMixin` class, which then will call the method next in the MRO.